# Solve for unknown value in R

Tags: r

I want to discount a number of cashflows and find the ''fair'' interest rate of a financial instrument. That is, I want to set the interest rate in such a way that
$$P=\sum_i^T e^{-ri}c_i$$, where P is some value. As a toy example, I came up with this:

```
value <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
discounted_value <- c()
for(i in 1:10){
  discounted_value[i] <- value[i]*exp(-r*i)
}
should_be_equal_to <- 50
```

I want to find a r such that the sum of the vector of discounted_values is equal to 50 (should_be_equal_to). Does anyone have an idea how to solve this? I prefer not to use a number of manual grids for r.

Comment: If you are looking for mathematical details on how to solve this, perhaps this question is then more suitable for math stackexchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's like a least square problem. You define a function that calculates the difference between the sum of your predicted value for a given `r` :

```
fn <- function(value,r) {   
         delta = 50 - sum(value*exp(-r*seq_along(value)))
         abs(delta)
     }
```

Then you optimize this function, providing boundaries:

```
optim(par = 0.5,fn=fn, value=value,method="Brent",lower=0,upper=1)

$par
[1] 0.01369665

$value
[1] 2.240363e-07

$counts
function gradient 
      NA       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
```

And you can try the optimized parameter:

```
r = 0.01369665
discounted_value = value*exp(-r*seq_along(value))
sum(discounted_value)
[1] 50
```